# How to use istool command in perl system() function

Tags: perl, automation, datastage

I am trying to put below command in perl system() function.But getting so many compilation errors (syntax).

```
./istool export -domain serviceshost:9080 -u dsadm -p password -ar test.isx -pre -ds '-base="ENGINEHOST/Dev_Project" Jobs/Batch/\*.*'
```

I was using it like in perl:

```
system("./istool export -domain serviceshost:9080 -u dsadm -p password -ar test.isx -pre -ds '-base="ENGINEHOST/Dev_Project" Jobs/Batch/\*.*'");
```

can some one guide me exactly how to use it in system function?I tried escaping . also with backslash(`\`) in front of it.

Comment: [edit] your post and show the errors you get; also show the escaped version.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Replace `system` with `print`, and it's obvious you didn't build the string correctly.

If you want to include a `"` in a string quoted with `"`, you need to escape it.
If you want to include a `\` in a double-quoted string, you need to escape it.